# Closure of an $\epsilon-$ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following question:

> Is {$x \in X| d(x,y) \le \epsilon $ } closed in $X$ for every metric space  $(X,d)$, every $y \in X$ and every $\epsilon > 0$?

In my opinion it is, because {$x \in X| d(x,y) \le \epsilon $ } is basically just the closure of an $\epsilon-$ball. I just wanted to check, if my answer is correct, because I heard some other students saying they found a counterexample to disprove it. If I'm wrong, could someone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is closed, but the closure of an open ball doesn't need to have this form.

Comment: It's closed, but it's not necessarily the closure of an $\epsilon$- open ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\{x\in X:d(x,y)\leq \varepsilon\}$ is closed for all $y\in X$ and all $\varepsilon>0$. One way to prove this is to show that the function $x\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous on $X$ for each fixed $y\in X$.

However, it is not always the case that $\{x\in X:d(x,y)\leq \varepsilon\}$ is the closure of $\{x\in X:d(x,y)< \varepsilon\}$. For instance, if $d$ is the discrete metric then $\{x\in X:d(x,y)<1\}$ is closed and is strictly contained in $\{x\in X:d(x,y)\leq 1\}$

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider the discrete metric. But could you elaborate why the continuity of $d(x,y)$ would lead to the statement in my post?

Comment: $\{x\in X:d(x,y)\leq \varepsilon\}$ is the inverse image of the closed set $[0,\varepsilon]$ under the continuous map $x\mapsto d(x,y)$, hence is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ y\not \in \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)=\{x \in X| d(x,y) \le \epsilon\}~~ i.e ~~~d(x,y)>\varepsilon .$$

for $$r=\frac{d(x,y)-\varepsilon }{2}>0$$  we have

$$B(y,r)\subset \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)^c \implies\bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)^c~~is ~open~~\Longleftrightarrow \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon) ~~~is ~~closed$$

Indeed, for $z\in B(y,r)$ since  $d(x,y)>\varepsilon $ we have

$$d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(y,z) <d(x,z) +r\\\implies d(x,z)> d(x,y)-r =d(x,y) -\frac{d(x,y)-\varepsilon }{2}=\frac{\varepsilon }{2} +\frac{d(x,y)}{2} >\varepsilon $$
that is $$ d(x,z)>\varepsilon \implies z\not\in \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)^c$$

Therefore,

$$B(y,r)\subset \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)^c \implies\bar{B}(x,\varepsilon)^c~~is ~open~~\Longleftrightarrow \bar{B}(x,\varepsilon) ~~~is ~~closed$$